# Any PHP editor from Microsoft available for Windows?

Tags: php, windows, editor

Does Microsoft offer any PHP editor or universal-programming-editor in general }except Notepad, of course ;) ? I know they have Visual Studio (VB, C#, C++, ...), but PHP support is not included.

is there any Microsoft product which allows this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dont know if there is any other MS product, but http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+visual+studio has lots of alternatives and even some answers showing how to use PHP with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin for VisualStudio [VS.Php](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/). Though it's not a Microsoft product, you can use VisualStudio to write your PHP code. I never used it myself and it's not free.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like something I should check closer.

Comment: It has build in CodeIgniter support for code completion etc. It is really a great product at first digh. I am coding in it right now and it seems to be the great choice. It is Visual Studio perfect environment in PHP world. What a great product. Thanks for this plugin.

Answer (score 6):

[**MS WebMatrix**](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) supports PHP, if I remember correctly *-- and it's free*.

Comment: If I may ask : why has this been downvoted ? Doesn't WebMatrix support PHP *(the features page says it does -- and a guy working at MS presented it last year, in a PHP conference in France)* ? Is it not offered by Microsoft ? Does it not work on windows ?

Comment: (The downvote has been cancelled, it seems : I no longer have a -1 on this answer ; I suppose it was a mistake ? still, thanks for the +1 to cancel the -1 ^^)

Comment: hmm, it is some kind of clicking environment. I need an editor or IDE and WebMatrix seems to me not like something I want to use. Anyway, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: If you want a full IDE, I would go with either Eclipse PDT or netbeans *(free)*, or PhpStorm *(costs about 100 €) -- even if those are not developped by MS*

Answer (score 1):

You mean developed by Microsoft? I'm just curious why would you want anything from them? :p

But if I'm just misunderstanding the question and you mean a program for Windows then I use Notepad++. I wish they had it for Linux but Bluefish isn't bad.

Comment: In this case, for bigger projects I prefer NetBeans. It's also free and a not just an editor, but a whole IDE.

Comment: Hmm, I think that Visual Studio is the best programming environment for VB and C# ever created. Have you ever worked with VS?

Comment: If I'm working with software or something those kind of programs are good, but if I'm just doing server side stuff I prefer a smaller program, just because it's less cluttered. THat could be the old OCD though

Answer (score 1):

Following are PHP editors provided by Microsoft;

1. Microsoft [Web Matrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) Free, cool and working best for me
2. Microsoft E[xpression Web](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=36179) Free, nice, alternative to Adobe Dreamweaver
3. VS.PHP [I have not tried it yet]

Answer (score 1):

Check out Visual Studio Code.
https://code.visualstudio.com/